# Kakfa SASL password rotate in each and every 24 hours

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Kafka password rotate each and every 24 hours. We have schedule that fetch latest password from file but how can we refresh Kafka consumers and producers with latest password.

Comment: Use a cron job? Kafka has no built in function for this, AFAIK

Comment: You mean, We should use cron expression to check password is rotated or not. If it is rotated then close older Kafka consumers and producers and create new one.
I think, this is not feasible option as creating consumer or producer take time and request need to wait for get new consumer or producer.

Comment: It's just one option. Doesn't matter how quickly it should take; it's a required step